# Nginx User Agent Rewrite

Tags: nginx, webserver

Aim: I would like to rewrite based on the below conditions:

- User agent is either Iphone or Blackberry
- There is not a "redirect=false" in the uri.

I have the below code which I thought would work, but doesn't. It just redirects all the time if the user agent is set, but ignores the `$uri` condition.

```
location / {
  if ( $uri  ~* "redirect=false" ) {
    set $var_redirect F;
  }

  if ( $http_user_agent ~* "iPhone|BlackBerry" ) {
    set $var_redirect "${var_redirect}M";
  }

  if ( $var_redirect = M ) {
    rewrite ^ http://m.domain.com redirect;
  }
}
```

The other option is to replace the redirect false condition with a only if location is / but not a sub folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `redirect=false` is sent in the parameters, I believe you need to replace `$uri` with `$args` in the `redirect=false` condition, later nginx versions can also use `if($arg_redirect = false)`